# I am not sure this question was closed as a duplicate correctly

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I recently posted an answer to this question:

- [How to Encoding and Decoding Base128 strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931648/99456)

and it was closed as a dupe to this question:

- [Why don't people use base128 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008047/why-dont-people-use-base128-in-javascript)

While these two questions are both related to Base128 I feel they don't have the same answer. In both cases the strong recommendation is to not use Base128 (for good reason) but the question about javascript does not tell you how to implement a C# solution (the original question). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Agreed, the first one to vote probably didn't notice/care enough and the others just followed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This seems to back that hypothesis: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2255062 . Are review voters allowed to select different duplicates when voting to close in that queue?

Comment: @Brad yes, clicking Close bring the ordinary close dialog exactly the same as inside the question itself - it's just made as part of the review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, the closure seems to be incorrect, the questions are certainly related but not duplicates. I suspect the C# question will be reopened soon now that you've brought it up on Meta. I wouldn't be surprised if there is an exact duplicate out there, but the Javascript question isn't it.

That said, and for future reference, there are a couple of things you could try *before* posting on Meta:

- Edit the question

  A single edit on a closed question will automatically enter it in the re-open queue, and the question in question has *a lot* of things you can fix.
- Flag for moderation attention

  These kind of issues can be resolved very quickly by a moderator, especially if your flag is precise. If the question has issues you can fix, please edit it before you flag it. It's a lot easier for your request to bring the desirable results if the question is at the best possible shape.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize there were other things I could do besides posting on Meta.

Comment: @MattJohnson Don't get me wrong, posting on Meta is fine, it's just not the more efficient way. Also, the question has been re-opened.