# What can be done about the amount of close votes on SO?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, vote-to-close

I have recently acquired the privilege to cast close/reopen votes. There are currently **54.3k** close votes on SO. And that amount is not decreasing.

Why are there so many? Aren't close votes disapperaing after a certain amount of time? If they are, why are they still in the queue?

Shouldn't something be done with all those votes? I mean, if there are really 50k+ votes queued for review, it means, that **there are probably 10k+ questions that are of very disputable quality**. Even if only a quarter of them really should be closed it's not good for SO, is it?

Perhaps there could be a certain threshold of close votes that automatically closes the question? For example if 20+ people mark a question as duplicate, it is done automatically without the need to review the votes.

Perhaps the reputation required for casting close votes should be lower?

Maybe there should be a reputation bonus for reviewing the questions? 1 rep for 10 valid and approved reviews or something like that?

Comment: "*if 20+ people mark a question as duplicate, it is done automatically*" => Actually the system only needs 5 votes to close a question without further review. The questions in the review queue are the ones which got at least 1 close vote but less than the 5 required to actually close it.

Comment: Given the issues we're already having with robo-reviewers, I don't think we should incentivize the Close Votes queue (or any review queue) any further.

Comment: @S.L.Barth robo-reviewers? what? Why would anyone write a robot to do reviews?

Comment: @Dariusz "robo-reviewers" is the term for people who blindly click their way through the review queue, just to get a badge.

Comment: Now imagine the mess if, instead of just getting a badge, they were rewarded with reputation... The review queues would then have very little relevance.

Comment: @syam agreed, I didn't think of that. I never seem to be able anticipate such behavior.

Comment: People are already getting lazy when voting to close in the queue, such as what happened in [this case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183074/i-am-not-sure-this-question-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-correctly), where four people rubber-stamped a bad close reason: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2255062 .